# Can't add objects to priority queue

Tags: java, queue, priority-queue

I need to add a Jedi object to a queue. None of the add methods that I know are working and all give the "cannot find symbol - method add(jedi1).I didn't learn much about Queues in my last class so I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing. Other things to note are 3 specifics of this.

1)Modify the heap operations to keep the maximum – rather than the minimum – element in the root. Refer to the Heap lab assignment for the algorithm.

2)  Utilize an array with a varying size limit (if <10% utilization reduce it by half; if full, double the size).

3)  Implement the heap to receive any generic object with a comparable method.

4)  Allow for duplicate value with the following rule: If a duplicate value is entered, the new element with similar value should be considered to have less priority than an existing element.

```
    public class PriorityQueue<JediQ>
    {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        public void main(String[] args)
    {
       while (true)
    {
        System.out.println("Please select an option");
        System.out.println("1 - Add a Jedi ");
        System.out.println("2 - Remove an element");
        System.out.println("3 - Print head value");
        System.out.println("4 - Compare value to head value");
        System.out.println("5 - Print Array");
        System.out.println("6 - Exit");
        int x = 0;
        x = reader.nextInt();

        if (x == 1)
        {
            PriorityQueue<JediQ> line = new PriorityQueue<JediQ>();
            System.out.println("Enter the name of the Jedi");
            String Name = reader.next();
            System.out.println("Enter the midi count");
            double midi = reader.nextInt();

            Jedi jedi1 = new Jedi(Name, midi);

            line.add(jedi1);

            System.out.print("Jedi was added");
        }
        if (x == 6)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You don't even have a method...

Comment: You have not actually written a PriorityQueue implementation yet, which is what you're supposed to do for your assignment.  All you have is a `main` method that uses the priority queue, and you have problems in your use of generics.  We aren't going to write the code for you, and if you're lost you need to talk to your professor.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is a vast lack of **basic** knowledge about everything; so I give you some things to start with:

First of all, that error message means: **your** implementation of that `PriorityQueue` ... does **not** have an `add()` method. Because: you didn't write it! So you start with something like:

```
public class PriorityQueue<T> {
  public void add(T newElement) { ...
```

Which leads to the second major problem: the usage of generic types. As you can see in my example, you say: "my queue class, should be accepting any kind of object". And only later on, when instantiating a queue object; then you declare that this instance should be for Jedis, like:

```
PriorityQueue<Jedi> jedis = new PriorityQueue<>();
jedies.add(lukeSkywalkerHisUnknownCousin);
```

But of course, the **real** fun within this exercise is the implementation of a priority queue, so that it provides all the methods that a queue should have; and that they work as outlined in your assignment! And obviously, that is your assignment, so I leave that as exercise to the reader!

Final hint: if you want to understand the methods you ought to implement, you can have a look at java's own [PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) and its methods!

Answer (score -1):

Use below method.

```
   line.offer(yourObject);
```

Please read the basics of collections framework. You able to add/ modify / delete objects out of any collections because the wrapper classes have provided the methods for that. 
For eg. When you add int ( that becomes Integer as collection only stores Object). the default Comparator is used. as below:

```
    public class PriorityQueueExample
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            //Creating a PriorityQueue with default Comparator.

            PriorityQueue<Integer> pQueue = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();

            //Inserting elements into pQueue.

            pQueue.offer(21);

            pQueue.offer(17);

            //Removing the head elements

            System.out.println(pQueue.poll());
```

To add custom objects in any collection you need to use either Comparator or Comparable.

```
   class JediQ
        {
            String name;

            int midi;

            //Constructor Of JediQ

            public JediQ(String name, int midi)
            {
                this.name = name;

                this.midi = midi;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString()
            {
                return name+" : "+midi;
            }
        }

   and then adding the object as below:

            class MyComparator implements Comparator<JediQ>
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(JediQ e1, JediQ e2)
            {
                return e1.name - e2.name;
            }
        }


        MyComparator comparator = new MyComparator();

        PriorityQueue<JediQ> pQueue = new PriorityQueue<JediQ>(7, comparator);
        pQueue.offer(new JediQ("AAA", 150));
```

Comment: @Cole you can use Comoparble here. you just need to add compareTo method in your Jediq bean.